# Why is $E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(t) f(t) dt$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $(\Omega,  P)$ be a probability space, $\Omega \subset \Bbb R$ and the probability measure be defined by a continious density function $f$. Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a random variable with an existing expected value $E(X)$. Then, we want to write:
>
> $E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(t) f(t) dt$.

Wherever I try to look it up, every site / book only tells me that this is how we want to define the expected value under the given premises. But I'm quite sure that there is an actual proof for it, becaue I can't really look behind it. Does anyone have an idea on this one?

Comment: This is wrong and conflates two distinct formulas, namely, $$E(X)=\int_\Omega X(\omega)dP(\omega)$$ and $$E(X)=\int_\mathbb Rxf(x)dx$$ where $f$ denotes the PDF of $X$.

Comment: What do you mean with proof? $E(X)$ has to be defined somehow, usually by the integral did wrote. Do you refer to an alternative definition?

Comment: Sorry, it's late, corrected the post.

Comment: It's exactly what's written in my lecture notes.

Answer (score 2):

When $X$ is discrete, its expectation is a weighted average of its values, weighted according to their probabilities, so that
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{x \in \mathrm{im}(X)} x \cdot \mathbb{P}\{X=x\} = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\})$$
Integrals are the continuous version of summation; the corresponding formula is therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} xf_X(x)\, dx = \int_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\Omega} X\, d\mathbb{P}$$
This is a definition, rather than something to be proved.

Answer (score 0):

(You don't say what $f$ is, but from context I will assume that it is a function chosen so that $dP = f(t) \,dt$.  Note that such a function does not necessarily exist.)

There's no *proof*, because as you say this is simply the definition.  But we can perhaps motivate why we chose this definition.

Consider the case where $\Omega$ is a finite set.  The expected value of a random variable is simply

$$\sum_{t \in \Omega} P(t) X(t)$$

In other words, the expected value is the sum of all possible outcomes weighted by the probability of each outcome.  I'll assume you're okay with this case.

So to define expected values in general, we just generalize this idea directly by replacing the sum with an integral and the individual probabilities with a probability measure.  Notice that if we take our probability measure to be discrete, we recover the original definition.

Comment: f is the density function.